# How to update elements inside an ArrayList of ArrayLists of Integers using stream map and reduce?

Tags: java, java-stream

Basically, I have an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> = [[-1,-4], [3,2], [0,-4], [-3,2]`. I want to use streams to go through each ArrayList and add the elements together like so: `[[-5],[5],[-4], [-1]]`. Then I want to convert it into an int[] array and end up with this: `[-5, 5, -4, -1]`.

I have this so far:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> outerNums = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ArrayList<Integer> innerNums0 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> innerNums1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> innerNums2 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> innerNums3 = new ArrayList<>();
        innerNums0.add(-1);
        innerNums0.add(-4);
        innerNums1.add(3);
        innerNums1.add(2);
        innerNums2.add(0);
        innerNums2.add(-4);
        innerNums3.add(-3);
        innerNums3.add(2);
        //
        outerNums.add(innerNums0);
        outerNums.add(innerNums1);
        outerNums.add(innerNums2);
        outerNums.add(innerNums3);
        
        
        
        System.out.println(res(outerNums));
    }
    
    public static int[] res(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> innerNums) {
        
        System.out.println(innerNums);
        //Need to use both map and reduce
        int[] result = innerNums.stream().map().reduce(); //not sure what to do here.
        
        return result;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this is what you are looking for?

```
List<List<Integer>> list = List.of(List.of(-1,-4), List.of(3,2), List.of(0,-4), List.of(-3,2));
int[] result = list.stream()
  .map(innerList -> innerList.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum))
  .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
  .toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

**Output**

```
[-5, 5, -4, -1]
```

Comment: Yes that's it. Thank you!

Comment: @AetherRemnant Side note, you can reduce this further by just using the `mapToInt` directly instead of going through the `map` method... `int[] result = list.stream().mapToInt(innerList -> innerList.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum)).toArray();`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`IntStream#sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--).

```
innerNums.stream().mapToInt(x -> x.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum()).toArray();
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/xrVgYn)

Answer (score 1):

For each inner list, stream and sum it up before collecting the sums into an array.

```
int[] result = outerNums.stream()
        .mapToInt(innerArrayList -> innerArrayList.stream()
                .mapToInt(i -> i)
                .sum())
        .toArray();
```

Note: `mapToInt` returns an `IntStream`.